# MySQL group by issue on text field (Field contain HTML)

Tags: mysql

I have a template table. A single template can have multiple HTML pages that stored in template_pages table.

A complete template is combination of multiple pages.

My requirement is to check duplicate templates. For that I have to match concatenate pages and match to check duplicates. I have build following query for that

```
Select Count(id) as count, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') as duplicate_templates from 
(select template_id as id, GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(template_pages.template) SEPARATOR ', ') as full_template from template_pages
    left join templates on templates.id = template_pages.template_id
    where template_pages.template != ""
    and templates.deleted_at IS NOT NULL
    group by template_id
) as templates
group by full_template having count(full_template) >1;
```

But this query not giving exact results. Its matching some unmatched records. Some template have some similar data but not exactly same also coming in duplicates.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

@ajay, seems you have issue at Where cluse with DELETE_AT column. Please verify that.

It's working for me.

[image]